# PHP – Why does some umlaut characters show while others don't?

Tags: php, character-encoding, output, special-characters, diacritics

This is a simplified version of the code I'm currently working with – why does it work fine when using a basic echo, but fails when trying to write only a part of the string? Should I add any encode/decode/locale/utf to make this work, in that case how?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
/* setlocale (LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8"); //this just gives me � (questionmark in a square) instead of the actual char*/

$str = "Två trötta träslag står i skogens övre kant";
echo ($str); // works fine with å ä ö

$words = str_word_count($str, 1, 'UTF-8');

echo ('<br>');

$first = join(" ", array_slice($words, 0, 5));
$last = join(" ", array_slice($words, -5, 5));
echo($first); // doesn't show å ä ö
echo ('<br>'); 
echo($last); // doesn't show å ä ö
echo ('<hr>');
?>
```

The output:

```
Två trötta träslag står i skogens övre kant
Tv tr tta tr slag
r i skogens vre kant
```

I've looked around for some of the most common suggestions, but either I'm implementing them wrong or they're not suitable for this in the first place (In my project I'll read the text from at .txt file if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the third parameter of [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/str_word_count) is `$charlist`, not `$charset`.

Hence, when you use `str_word_count()`, it not only splits on the spaces but the UTF-8 characters too. This is easy to verify:

```
$str = "Två trötta träslag står i skogens övre kant";
print_r(str_word_count($str, 1));
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Tv
    [1] => tr
    [2] => tta
    [3] => tr
    [4] => slag
    [5] => st
    [6] => r
    [7] => i
    [8] => skogens
    [9] => vre
    [10] => kant
)
*/
```

There are two solutions to this: if you only want to split on spaces, you can use this instead:

```
$words = explode(' ', $str);
```

However, if you're hell bent on using `str_word_count()`, you can add the UTF-8 characters manually:

```
$words = str_word_count($str, 1, 'åäö');
```

Comment: Oh, it didn't occur to me that I split the UTF-8 characters as well. And cheers for providing a way to debug along with alternative solutions – `explode` will be perfectly sufficient at this time!